# display text entered in an input box to the console

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to get text entered in an input box to display in the console, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The error that comes up says "Uncaught ReferenceError: enteredText is not defined". I am using knockout.

HTML

```
<input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search" data-bind="value: enteredText, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
```

JavaScript

```
var viewModel = {
  enteredText: ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
console.log(viewModel.enteredText);
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with your code _as you've described_, although you'd probably want to invoke the observable: `viewModel.enteredText()`, and that doing it immediately after applying bindings is always going to give you the original value: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zs2pghy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the update in real time, you can subscribe to the observable and then log every time it changes:

```js
var viewModel = {
  enteredText: ko.observable("")
};

viewModel.enteredText.subscribe(function(newValue){
  console.log(viewModel.enteredText());
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search" data-bind="value: enteredText, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
```